# Automatic next song makes seekbar and buttons crash

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android programming. I followed a mediaplayer tutorial but I'm now trying to make it more advance, the only problem is thats not working as expected.

When the song is finished it should start playing the next song, but doesn't update my seekbar (only updates Max) and it makes my buttons crash my app. I tried many things but can't fix it myself. If i press the next button however (before music track ends) the buttons and seekbar work.

What I'm want is my seekbar to reset for the new song and go again, and i want my buttons to work after the onCompletion next song.

Here my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    btPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btPlay);
    btNxt = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btNxt);
    btPv = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btPv);

    btPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    btNxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    btPv.setOnClickListener(this);

    sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    updateSeekBar = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int TotalDuration = mp.getDuration();
            int currentPosition = 0;
            while (currentPosition < TotalDuration) try {
                sleep(500);
                currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                sb.setProgress(currentPosition);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();

        mp.release();
    }
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    mySongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");
    position = b.getInt("pos", 0);

    u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            try {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                position = (position + 1) % mySongs.size();
                u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
                sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                mp.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    mp.start();
    sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
    updateSeekBar.start();

    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.btPlay:
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.pause();
                btPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            } else {
                mp.start();
                btPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btNxt:
            try {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    position = (position + 1) % mySongs.size();
                    u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
                    mp.start();
                    sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            break;
        case R.id.btPv:
            try {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    position = (position - 1 < 0) ? mySongs.size() - 1 : position - 1;
                    u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
                    mp.start();
                    sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
}
```

}

Errors (in android Monitor):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Comment: Add the errorlogs and stackTrace

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace? It really helps to figure out the problem.